# how to configure the style with css in a react project with an extern css-file

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router

I'm really frustrated. I working on my first react project and can't configure the style with an extern file. I have an **src** folder which contains the **App.js & App.css** files, in this folder, I also included a component folder. When I'm writing the style information into the same file it's working:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Header() {
    return (
        <header >
            <h1>P-Software</h1>
            <p>
            <Link to="/Start" style={linkStyle}>Home</Link>

            </p>
        </header>
    )
}

const linkStyle = {
    color: '#fff',
    textDecoration: 'none',
}

export default Header;
```

But if I'm trying to include the css information from the App.css it says:

> 'linkStyle' is not defined

**the Header.js:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../App.css';


function Header() {
    return (
        <header >
            <h1>P-Software</h1>
            <p>
            <Link to="/Start" style={linkStyle}>Home</Link>
            </p>
        </header>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

**App.css:**

```
/*
some other styles
*/

.linkStyle {
  background-color: brown;
  color: '#fff';
  padding: '10px'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use :

import '../App.css'

For Header.js

It will work. Happy coding!

Comment: Thats exactly what i already did? or im getting something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

found out whats realy wrong. Just need to
declare the element as class of something cause css is looking for it.
--> change **style={...}** to **className="..."**

```
import '../App.css';

//....

// wrong  <Link to="/Start" style={linkStyle}>Home</Link>       
<Link to="/Start" className="linkStyle">Home</Link> 

// ....
```